# When uploading a file to Google Drive must you stay on the page?

Tags: google-drive

When uploading to Google Drive must one leave the web page open that is doing the upload? I tested and navigated away from the page and when I came back, even though the upload was around 90%, it appeared to have been completely deleted. Is there a way either to allow the upload to continue in the background or to resume at a later time?

Comment: Why not just leave Google Drive open in a separate tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No, for the upload to continue, you must have the page open (can be open in a minimized window or other tab)

Alternative: Google Drive for Desktop. Automatic two-way syncing in background, allows manual pausing and auto-resume on network connection loss.